# Value of $\prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n^2+1}{n^2-1}$

Tags: products

Consider the following product:
$$\prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{n^2+1}{n^2-1} = \prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1+\frac{1}{n}}{1-\frac{1}{n}}\approx 3.67608...$$
It seems to be close to [OEIS A156648](http://oeis.org/A156648), i.e. $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} 1+\frac{1}{n^2}$, which is also expressible as $\frac{\sinh(\pi)}{\pi}$.
Is the first product expressible in similar closed form?

Comment: That's only the partial product form (just checked myself). OP presumably wants an exact value for the product itself - hypothetically you could take $m \rightarrow \infty$, but that sems messy with four different gamma functions

Comment: @g3nuine Note that we indeed have $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=\frac{\sinh(\pi)}{\pi}$, as given in your OEIS link, but $$\prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1^2}}\cdot \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=\frac{\sinh(\pi)}{2\pi}$$

Comment: @projectilemotion You're right my bad, copy paste error. I've edited it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write your product as
$$\prod_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}$$
and then notice that the product of the denominators telescopes:
$$\prod_{n=2}^\infty \bigg(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\bigg)=\prod_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(n+1)(n-1)}{n^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$
making your product equal to
$$2\prod_{n=2}^\infty \bigg(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\bigg)=\frac{\sinh(\pi)}{\pi}$$

Comment: Hi, I believe your answer is currently incorrect. $2\sinh(\pi)/\pi \approx 7.35$; however, Wolfram Alpha says that the product equals $3.676\ldots$ Seems like you're off by a factor of $2$.

Comment: @Ekesh Ah, this is because the OP's closed form should be $\sinh(\pi)/2\pi$. I will fix it.